# Laravel Session::getId() is different on login and logout

Tags: laravel, session, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

i have table `user_logins` to maintain multiple login information about user

table structure for `user_logins` :

```
    'session_id',
    'user_id',
    'ip_address',
    'user_agent',
    'browser_name',
    'location',
    'login_at',
    'is_active'
```

i have [UserEventSubscriber](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events#event-subscribers) listener with 2 functions like below :

```
public function handleUserLogin($event) {
     UserLogin::create([
        'session_id'=>Session::getId(),
        ...
     ]);
}
```

im getting `Session::getId() = mpT6RDsl54JExkejrqf3fnYiFLzbR2pTb2qfNHBe` in `handleUserLogin` function

now when user logout i want to update / delete the table entry from user_logins table where session_id = Session::getId()

```
 public function handleUserLogout($event) {
        dd(Session::getId());
        //UserLogin::where('session_id',Session::getId())->delete();
 }
```

on handleUserLogout function im getting a different session id

`Session::getId() qLYngAx1Vs8VBhxm0oCKZO3fDwun02UEXRyDm0Hi` so im unable to update/delete entry in `user_logins` table

i have seen `sessions` table have id `qLYngAx1Vs8VBhxm0oCKZO3fDwun02UEXRyDm0Hi` which is same as id i get on logout function .

so my question is why im getting a different session id on user login function ? and what should i do to get same session id using `Session::getId()` in handleUserLogin and handleUserLogout function .

Comment: Do you use any js framework to logout or just send POST web request?

Comment: just send POST request

Comment: `<a class="dropdown-item p-2 header-menu-logout-link" href="{{ route('logout') }}" title="Logout" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"><span  style="margin-right:9px;"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></span>Logout</a>
                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display:none;">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                        </form>

                        </div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that , need to override `sendLoginResponse` from [AuthenticatesUsers](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php) in `Auth/LoginController`

`$request->session()->regenerate()` generates new session id after login , so if you want to get same id as before , comment out that line .

```
 protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        // $request->session()->regenerate();   <-- this line is generating new session after user login 
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also needed the old session Id when handling `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login` events.
Found two additional options.

- get it from session cookie; e.g. `request()->cookies()->get(session()->getName())`,
- or listen to an earlier event e.g. `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Attempting` and store the current Id in the session somewhere. That way you can check for it in `Login` event handler.

Answer (score -1):

You, sir, are my hero. I was experiencing the same issue, but as I am using Fortify the code I needed to comment out was in the following file:

```
/vendor/laravel/fortify/src/Actions/PrepareAuthenticatedSession.php
```

The first line of the `handle` function reads:

```
$request->session()->regenerate();
```

Comment that out and the session id does not regenerate after authentication.

For future Googlers, this was also causing a 419 status code to be returned in ajax requests (that were passing the CSRF token obtained from a meta tag on the page) following a successful login made via an ajax request.

Comment: Careful: As Mtxz points out here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67176551/2917183 you should never edit the files in vendor as they will likely be overwritten by future updates.

Comment: In addition to changing vendor files always being a bad idea, commenting out security features to make a page work is also generally not a good solution either, and certainly not one that should be recommended to others. In the case of sessions changing, some sites (like github) prompt at the top of the page with a reload button to refresh the session when they detect that the user signed in on another tab. This requires some extra work to implement, but is a better solution. I'm sure there are other solutions as well.